# Finding number of all nested cells in a complex cell

Tags: matlab, nodes, cell, cells

I have a nested cell which represents a tree-structure:

```
CellArray={1,1,1,{1,1,1,{1,1,{1,{1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1}, 1,1},1,1},1,1,1},1,1,1,{1,1,1,1}};
```

I want to find out the number of **nodes** in Matlab. I put a simple picture below that might help you understand what I am looking for more precisely:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, you could use `numel(myTreeArray)` to get this result, where `myTreeArray` is the output of the function `getTreeArray` in my answer to your [**more recent question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666560/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of cell elements, that are themselves cells. 
Then you can go recursively through your cell cells (and numbers) and check with `iscell` to see which elements are cells. See the following, where totnod ultimately gives the number of nodes.

```
ind=cellfun(@iscell, Chains);
totnod=sum(ind);
oldtmp=Chains(ind);
while ~isempty(oldtmp)
       newtmp={};
       for i=1:length(oldtmp)
           ind=cellfun(@iscell, oldtmp{i});
           newtmp=[newtmp,oldtmp{i}(ind)];
           totnod=totnod+sum(ind);
       end
       oldtmp=newtmp;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler approach using a single [`while`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) loop and repeated concatenation of the sub-cells:

```
temp = CellArray;
nNodes = 0;
while iscell(temp)
  index = cellfun(@iscell, temp);
  nNodes = nNodes + sum(index);
  temp = [temp{index}];
end
```

And the result for the sample `CellArray` in the question:

```
nNodes =

     5
```