# Ploting a nested cell as a tree using treeplot: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, tree, cells

I have a complex cell that represents a tree structure:

```
CellArray = {1,1,1,{1,1,1,{1,1,{1,{1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1}, 1,1}, 1,1},1,1,1},1,1,1,{1,1,1,1}};
```

I want to plot the representative tree from it by using `treeplot(p)`, but I'm not sure how to construct the array `p` for it to display correctly.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? Or what problems you are facing?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665684/finding-number-of-all-nested-cells-in-a-complex-cell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can create a recursive function, which explores your cell array and creates a tree pointer array (as described in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/treeplot.html)) to each node's parent.

This function takes a cell array (like the one in your question) which contains either scalars or nested cell arrays.

---

#### `treebuilder` logic:

1. If an item is a scalar, assign it a parent node number, increment node number by 1
2. If an item is a cell array, run `treebuilder` on that cell, returning the maximum node number which was reached (along with the generated sub-tree).
3. Recursive function because of step 2, so repeat until every element done

---

#### Function:

```
function treearray = getTreeArray(cellarray)
    % initialise the array construction from node 0
    treearray = [0, treebuilder(cellarray, 1)]; 
    % recursive tree building function, pass it a cell array and root node
    function [out, node] = treebuilder(cellarray, rnode)
        % Set up variables to be populated whilst looping
        out = []; 
        % Start node off at root node
        node = rnode;
        % Loop over cell array elements, either recurse or add node
        for ii = 1:numel(cellarray)
            tb = []; node = node + 1;
            if iscell(cellarray{ii})
                [tb, node] = treebuilder(cellarray{ii}, node);
            end
            out = [out, rnode, tb];   
        end
    end
end
```

---

#### Usage with simple example

Here is a more simple example than yours, so we can check logic works easily.

```
myCellArray = {1 1 {1 1 1 {1 1 1}}};
% This cell array has 3 levels: 
% - 3 child nodes (2,3,4) of the root node (1) 
% - Last node on the first level (4) has 4 children:
%     - 4 child nodes on second level (5,6,7,8) 
%     - Last node on the first level (8) has 3 children:
%         - 3 child nodes on third level (9,10,11)
myTreeArray = getTreeArray(myCellArray);
% Output, we see the corresponding nodes as listed above:
% [0 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 8 8 8]
treeplot(myTreeArray)
```

[image: simple]

---

#### Your cell array

I think this works as expected, note you don't have to define the `myCellArray` or `myTreeArray` variables:

```
treeplot(getTreeArray({1,1,1,{1,1,1,{1,1,{1,{1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1}, 1,1}, 1,1},1,1,1},1,1,1,{1,1,1,1}}))
```

Here is the [**output image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPkY5.png), showing that the algorithm can cope with the more complicated tree. Speed doesn't seem too bad either, although displaying *extremely* complicated trees will be fairly redundant anyway!

---

#### Edit: Labelling the nodes

You can label the nodes by getting their position using [`treelayout`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/treelayout.html) and keeping track of the values as you encounter them when building the tree array. The function should be tweaked for this "keeping track" like so:

```
function [treearray, nodevals] = getTreeArray(cellarray)
    % initialise the array construction from node 0
    [nodes, ~, nodevals] = treebuilder(cellarray, 1); 
    treearray = [0, nodes];
    % recursive tree building function, pass it a cell array and root node
    function [out, node, nodevals] = treebuilder(cellarray, rnode)
        % Set up variables to be populated whilst looping
        out = []; nodevals = {};
        % Start node off at root node
        node = rnode;
        % Loop over cell array elements, either recurse or add node
        for ii = 1:numel(cellarray)
            node = node + 1;
            if iscell(cellarray{ii})
                [tb, node, nv] = treebuilder(cellarray{ii}, node);
                out = [out, rnode, tb];  
                nodevals = [nodevals, nv];
            else
                out = [out, rnode];
                nodevals = [nodevals, {node; cellarray{ii}}];
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

**Note**: You could use a similar adaptation to keep track of the node *number* instead of the node *value* if you wanted to number each node on the plot.

I have used a cell array here so that **you could have text or numerical values on each node**. If you only ever want numerical values, it may shorten the post-formatting to store `nodevals` in a matrix instead.

Then to plot this you can use

```
% Run the tree building script above
[treearray, nodevals] = getTreeArray(myCellArray);
% Plot
treeplot(treearray);
% Get the position of each node on the plot  
[x,y] = treelayout(treearray);
% Get the indices of the nodes which have values stored
nodeidx = cell2mat(nodevals(1,:));
% Get the labels (values) corresponding to those nodes. Must be strings in cell array
labels = cellfun(@num2str, nodevals(2,:), 'uniformoutput', 0);
% Add labels, with a vertical offset to the y coords so that labels don't sit on nodes
text(x(nodeidx), y(nodeidx) - 0.03, labels);
```

Example output for the cell `myCellArray = {{17, 99.9}, 50}`, where I've chosen those numbers to make it clear they're not the actual "node number"!

[image]

Comment: Worked Perfect! Thanks for the explanation & the comment lines

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your valuable knowledge :)