# Random selection of a member's location in a nested cell of cells: Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, random, cell-array

I have a nested cell of cells like the one below:

`CellArray={1,1,1,{1,1,1,{1,1,{1,{1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1}, 1,1},1,1},1,1,1},1,1,1,{1,1,1,1}};`

I need to randomly pick a location in `CellArray`. All members' locations of `CellArray` must have same chances to be chosen in the random selection process. Thanks.

Comment: You may find a slight connection between this question and [**the previous one of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665684/finding-number-of-all-nested-cells-in-a-complex-cell)

Comment: What would be some examples of a random location?

Comment: Do you mean that each `1` should have an equal chance of selection, as per the sample array shown?

Comment: @rayryeng The example could be `CellArray{1}` or `CellArray{4}{4}{1}` or any other member's location in the nested cell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can capture the output of the `celldisp` function. Then use regex to extrcat indices:

```
s=evalc('celldisp(CellArray,'''')');
m = regexp(s, '\{[^\=]*\}', 'match');
```

- Thanks to @excaza that suggested a clearer use of regexp

Result:

```
m =
{
  [1,1] = {1}
  [1,2] = {2}
  [1,3] = {3}
  [1,4] = {4}{1}
  [1,5] = {4}{2}
  [1,6] = {4}{3}
  [1,7] = {4}{4}{1}
  [1,8] = {4}{4}{2}
  [1,9] = {4}{4}{3}{1}
  [1,10] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{1}
  [1,11] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{2}
  [1,12] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{3}
  [1,13] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{4}
  [1,14] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{5}
  [1,15] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{6}
  [1,16] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{7}
  [1,17] = {4}{4}{3}{2}{8}
  [1,18] = {4}{4}{3}{3}
  [1,19] = {4}{4}{3}{4}
  [1,20] = {4}{4}{4}
  [1,21] = {4}{4}{5}
  [1,22] = {4}{5}
  [1,23] = {4}{6}
  [1,24] = {4}{7}
  [1,25] = {5}
  [1,26] = {6}
  [1,27] = {7}
  [1,28] = {8}{1}
  [1,29] = {8}{2}
  [1,30] = {8}{3}
  [1,31] = {8}{4}
}
```

Use `randi` to select an index:

```
m{randi(numel(m))}
```

Comment: You can get the same result from `regexp` with `m = regexp(s, '\{[^\=]*\}', 'match');`, which I would argue is a clearer representation of what the user is getting out of the regex. Still, very clever, +1

Comment: @rahnema1,@excaza  _Thank you for sharing your valuable knowledge._

Comment: @Amin Glad if it can help!

Comment: @rahnema1 **Just as a minor additional question, if I want to change the value of the location which is chosen in the `CellArray`, how can I do that?**

Comment: @Amin `eval` may help. `idx = 5;value = 3;eval(['CellArray' m{idx} '=' num2str(value) ';'])`

Comment: @rahnema1 Thanks a million!